# Encoding issue when setting a content using javascript in android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webview, xss

In webview I will be loading static html file with css.

`webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/customhtml.html`

In that html I have also set encoding in meta tag as `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`

After this file is loaded I will be setting content as

`webView.loadUrl("javascript:setContent(" + JSONObject.quote(content)+")");`

here is javascript

```
`function setContent(contentToSet)
{ 
    setBaseURL();
    var mailContentElement = document.getElementById('mailcontentid'); 
    mailContentElement.innerHTML = ""
    handleContentinHTML($('mailcontentid'),contentToSet);
    androidResponse(true);   //method to call android js interface
}

function handleContentinHTML (contentEl, value)
{
    contentEl.innerHTML = value;
}`
```

Problem: When setting contentlike `filename=0000%3Cimg%20src%3da%20onerror%3dalert(test)%3Eb4911111`  this gets converted to html image tag and alert message is shown. This content is not displayed exactly as in text form.

some tests I tried:

1 - settinge encoding in webview settings `settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");`

2 - convert the html file to string and load as `myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, convertfiletohtmlString, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`  and setting the content using javascript.

3 - using `escape(contentToSet)` in javascript ;

Nothing seems to work. Please help me an post your suggestions.

Comment: Set the `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not check this in lower versions at first. When I checked, it was working fine in lower versions < kitkat. Finally I realized the we need to use `evaluateJavascript()` for executing javascripts post kitkat. When I used this the problem was solved. But till not sure why loadUrl() not support encoding for executing javascripts.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Yes! I came across an edge case where some arbitrary json content (escaped using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript) threw this error:
Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

But if I use evaluateJavascript the error does not occur. I'm going to take your word for it that loadUrl works in versions lower than SDK 19 :-D

Answer (score 0):

Make an HTML escape function:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return String(str)
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
            .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
            .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

(taken from the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124052/413180) to this question).

Then change your function to call this:

```
function handleContentinHTML (contentEl, value)
{
    contentEl.innerHTML = htmlEscape(value);
}
```

Although if you are using JQuery you could just use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) to set this:

```
function handleContentinHTML (contentEl, value)
{
    contentEl.text(value);
}
```

Comment: This does not work in my case :( , because the content I get will be in encoded form only. I only need to decode some special chars like this case.